# Not able to view triggers even the triggers are present in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 triggers present in three different tables. I want to list them all in MySQL

I have used multiple queries but all returning empty rows

```
show triggers;
```

```
select trigger_schema, trigger_name, action_statement from information_schema.triggers
```

```
select * from information_schema.triggers where information_schema.triggers.trigger_schema like '%my_db_name%'
```

```
SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE '<tablename>'
```

All the above queries returns nothing but the triggers are present

Comment: How do you 'know' they are present if none of the above VALID QUERIES produce anything?

Comment: I have a list of the triggers which are created.

Comment: I have also checked by inserting as all of them are insert triggers.

Comment: Where did you get that list and are you inferring that the triggers exist by outcome? Personally I would reboot everything and run your published queries again.

Comment: But the triggers are working

Comment: Check SHOW GRANTS for current account. Maybe it have no needed permissions?

Comment: I have done **SHOW GRANTS**. Below is the output

`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password' 
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON 'db_name'.* TO 'user'@'%'`

Comment: Tushar Sureka of you want to get someones attention include their name in a comment preceded by @

Comment: @P.Salmon Will remember next time. I can't edit my comment now